# mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Tags: php

My code is this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And it's always giving me the

> mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

You're running a query on the first line, which returns a "resource" as a result of the query.  Then on the immediate next line you try to use that resource as another query to run again.  You don't need the second line, the `$result` can be set in the first line.

Answer (score 3):

You have some unnecessary/wrong lines in your code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I guess you wanted to write:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Is incorrect.  You should just be assigning the query string to `$query` - what you're doing is running the query once, then trying to run the result of the query as a query again.  You should have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

which would give you the results you seek.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is here `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");`

then you are running `mysql_query($query)` and it's trying to run the command against the resultset returned by the first statement, not a string like it should actually be

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Change it for:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from those lines:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Your calling the `mysql_query()` function twice.

You can do:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Or either:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM tb_funcionario" );
```